# Best practice for setting focus to a Swing control in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, focus

One school of thought says to add a window listener and set focus when the windowOpened event fires:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){ 
  public void windowOpened( WindowEvent e){ 
    txtMessage.requestFocus();
  } 
});
```

The other school of thought says to use the SwingUtilities.invokeLater method to set focus in a separate thread.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
  public void run() {
    field.requestFocus();
  }
});
```

Can anyone tell me which is best practice or when you would choose one over the other?
When using the threaded solution, is it possible for the thread to get lost and focus never set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All updates to the GUI must be done on the Event-Dispatch Thread (EDT).  If you're unsure whether or not you're on it, invokeLater(...) will always guarantee it.  It won't harm anything if you use it and don't need it.

Also, you should use `field.requestFocusInWindow();`

Comment: We are going to try this solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){ 
  public void windowOpened( WindowEvent e){ 
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run() {
      field.requestFocusInWindow();
      }
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @nalply this answer the question exactly - it show best practise on how to update swing components, in given example how to take focus for component. `field` you can replace with any swing componet you need to update.

Comment: There is no need to use invokeLater() since event listeners execute on the EDT.

Comment: @camickr I think that required in most cases to delay this event for JTextComponents (used as editors component too) with added DocumentListener firing events everywhere,

Comment: @mKorbel, yes, in some cases, but not in this case.

Comment: @camickr in contrast with your great code I'm used `container.setVisible(true)` wrapped into `invokeLater`, and next code (inside invokeLater()) line is `another void` with `whatever.requestFocusInWindow()` wrapped in `invokeLater` too,

Comment: So you're saying to use a combination of the two?  Interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use `requestFocusInWindow()` not requestFocus().

I prefer the second approach. I think it will work in all cases.

Panels should be created independently of the Window (JFrame or JDialog) that they will be added to so the panel will not have a reference to the Window when it is constructed. For example:

```
JPanel panel = new CustomPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add( panel );
```

For a third approach you can check out the [RequestFocusListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/).